# Firestore listener killed when app goes in background for a long time

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my app I'm listening for a Firestore query whenever the user signs in. After the app goes in background for some time, the listener gets cancelled and the client doesn't get notified of any new changes.

How do I know if a listener has been cancelled by the SDK? What's the proper way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On most operating system this is done automatically by the system itself, in order to preserve battery life. Whether it is possible to detect this situation, and how, depends on the OS.

In most cases it is better to depend on another mechanism to deliver updates to an app that is not actively being used, such as Firebase Cloud Messaging - which you can call from for example Cloud Functions to deliver messages to backgrounded apps. For an example of this, see the Firebase documentation on [notifying users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank for your answer! Currently my main issue with this is that when users come back to the app, the listener has silently been killed and I'd be showing stale data. 
So should I register the listener again (and kill the previous one) whenever the app comes back from background? This feels like what the Firestore SDK should be doing. Has anyone brought up this feature request with you?

Comment: You might want to check if the listener actually is silently killed, or whether the failure listener fires for it. If it is indeed silently happening, I guess you'll need to detect the app restore and reattach the listeners. Typically this should happen automatically if you attach your listeners in a lifecycle event such as `onResume` (and thus remove them in `onPause`).