# Alert with closed app or in background - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When receiving new data in the database,
is it possible to issue an alert on the mobile home screen even with the app closed or in the background?

**In the code below, I receive a list of calls. I would like to warn the user, whenever there is a new call.**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        title: Text("Chamados"),
      ),
      body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getChamados(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return new Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0 || tid == null || tid == "") {
                  return new Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Nenhum Chamado.',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                            elevation: 8.0,
                            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 6.0, vertical: 5.0),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration:
                                  BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF00aacb)),
                              child: ListTile(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 1.0),
                                // leading: Container(
                                //   padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                                //   decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                //       border: new Border(
                                //           right: new BorderSide(
                                //               width: 2.0,
                                //               color: Colors.white))),
                                //   child: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble,
                                //       color: Colors.white),
                                // ),
                                title: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      'Apoio solicitado',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text(
                                        'ID: ' +
                                            snapshot.data[index].data['tid']
                                                .toString(),
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                subtitle: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                        nome.toString(),
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text(
                                        snapshot.data[index].data['dateTime']
                                            .toString(),
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 28,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    String titulo = "Apoio solicitado";
                                    String conteudo =
                                    snapshot.data[index].data['sinal'].toString() == "A"
                                    ? "O botão localizado no console foi pressionado. Data e hora: "+snapshot.data[index].data['dateTime'].toString()
                                    :(snapshot.data[index].data['sinal'].toString() == "B"
                                    ? "O botão localizado no banco traseiro, lado esquerdo, foi pressionado. Data e hora: "+snapshot.data[index].data['dateTime'].toString()
                                    :(snapshot.data[index].data['sinal'].toString() == "C"
                                    ? "O botão localizado no banco traseiro, lado direito, foi pressionado. Data e hora: "+snapshot.data[index].data['dateTime'].toString()
                                    :(snapshot.data[index].data['sinal'].toString() == "D"
                                    ? "O botão localizado no porta-malas foi pressionado. Data e hora: "+snapshot.data[index].data['dateTime'].toString() : "")));
                                    alertDialog(context, titulo, conteudo);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ));
                      });
                }
              },
            ))
          ]),
    );
  }
```

I tried to use push notification, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was unsuccessful about using push notifications? I don't think think it will work without a backend pushing the notification, possibly if the app is running in the background. A simple solution would be to use a Google Cloud Function which waits for the changes in the database, then send a Google Cloud Message (push notification) through that function.

See this article for details on how to do this:

[Send Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) or Push notification to a topic using cloud function when real-time database value changes.](https://medium.com/@jerinamathews/send-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-to-a-topic-using-cloud-function-when-realtime-database-value-fa78fa758549)

Comment: I was trying to use notification in another way. I will read this article and do a test. Soon return with the result.

Comment: In this article, he shows you how to submit to a topic. Is there any way to send using the token? In my database (firestore), I have the token of each user saved. Can I get the token and send the notification to the user who had a change in the database?

Comment: Yes you can. In the cloud function you listen to a change at a certain place, get the userID/userToken where the change happened (and any other necessary data from Firestore), then send the push notification. I'm not sure if you've used cloud functions before but they're quite useful and pretty simple to use.

Comment: I know little about these services, but I will try to do the tests.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for a mobile app to reliably continue listening to Firestore updates when the app is not actively being used. Operating systems at that point may kill connections to reduce battery usage.

The only way to (relatively) reliably deliver notifications to a backgrounded app is by listening for the changes on a server, and then using FCM/APNS to deliver a push notification  to the device.

See for example:

- [Notify users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) in the Cloud Functions documentation.
- [Sending notifications between Android devices with Firebase Database and Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) on the Firebase blog
- [Firestore listener killed when app goes in background for a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196357/firestore-listener-killed-when-app-goes-in-background-for-a-long-time)

Comment: Thank you, I will read the articles and take the tests.